# I want to know the difference between insert tag and update tag in spring mybatis

Tags: spring, oracle, mybatis

I'm using mybatis in spring and spring version is 4.

When using Oracle insert all as:

```
<insert id = "testMultipleInserts"  parameterType="java.util.List">
<foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index" open="insert all" close="select * from dual" separator=" " >
    Into Test_A (Description) values (#{element.description})
</foreach>
</insert>
```

If you run this way, you'll get an error.

```
 <update id = "testMultipleInserts"  parameterType="java.util.List">
<foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index" open="insert all" close="select * from dual" separator=" " >
    Into Test_A (Description) values (#{element.description})
</foreach>
</update>
```

It's going all too well when you run like this. I wonder if there is an update difference between insert in tag. I know *insert* and *update* tags have no difference in mybatis. Is there any specific way to set up springs or mybatis?

Comment: You should include the error that you get.